# Generics error in array list

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist

I'm creating an application and I have a `FragmentPager` that I use. To use `FragmentPager` I must support it with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I have an interface that I've built the called `Nameable` and I want to create an array list that you can put there `Fragments` that implements the `Nameable` interface.

I've tried those ways but it gives me an error, and I don't really know why because it's a java thing and there are a lot of examples like this over the internet.

This is what I've tried:

```
private ArrayList<Fragment extends Nameable> mFragmentList;
```

The error:

> Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Other thing (which is not so right way to do it but I tried it to)

```
private ArrayList<? extends Fragment & Nameable> mFragmentList;
```

The error:

> Syntax error on token "&", , expected

Why does this statement give me an error? I'm pretty sure that's the right way to do it.

Thanks, Elad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList;
```

`extends` and `super` in generics signatures are used to constrain type parameters, not actual types. That `Fragment` implements `Nameable` is already defined in the `Fragment` class, you don't need to repeat that everywhere.

Comment: Of course, but I do want to constrain the type, because I need it. Example:  
`@Override
  public String getTitle(int position) {
   return mFragmentList.get(position).getName();
  }`

Comment: Wait, you mean that `Fragment` doesn't implement `Nameable`? If so, make a class/interface that does, and make the list of its type.

Comment: No, Fragment doesn't implements Nameable.  
It's a bit complicated, Fragment has some subclasses, and I want to put in this list Fragments subclasses, and Fragment subclasses subclasses (let's say ListFragment extend Fragment and my class extends ListFragment) and they all must implement Nameable. Did you understand?

Comment: Then you need to make some sort of `NameableFragment` class or interface, and store that in the list.

Comment: But if I'll make NameableFragment that extends Fragment I won't be able to put objects of classes that extends ListFragment (a subclass of Fragment).

Comment: And possibly hit the generics bible: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html. The relevant section is the one on [type parameter bounds](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Bounds) – which only constrain allowable type parameters, and can't be used as type parameters themselves.

Comment: If you have multiple subclasses of `Fragment` that are `Nameable`, `NameableFragment` should be an interface that these subclasses implement. `NameableFragment` should contain the public methods of `Fragment` you need, and extend from `Nameable`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7351/discussion-between-elad92-and-inerdial)